# How to override Prime ng styles

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

How to change style

```
.p-dialog .p-dialog-footer button {
   margin: 0 1rem 0 0 !important;
   width: auto !important;
}
```

I write like this but it doesn't work

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dialog .p-dialog-footer button {
   width: 2.5rem !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original `width` is declared `!important`. Your override then has to be `!important` too.

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: The !important was necessary, but not sufficient. One more thing I can think of: Since this is for a dialog, the dialog isn't really contained inside your :host component, even though you might be launching the dialog from there. So this change needs to be a global style (as in styles.scss). You might need to create a new class for the dialog if you don't want all dialogs to have this change.